# Azure AD B2C returns a different access token than Postman

Tags: blazor, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, blazor-webassembly

I'm having an issue getting an access token from Azure AD B2C to access my Azure Functions api app. When I use Postman with an Auth URL like this.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant id>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
```

I get an access token that decodes to something like this. Notice the "ver" is 2.0 and the "azp" matches the "aud" which is the id of my Azure Functions app registered in Azure AD B2C. With this access token, I can successfully call a function from the Azure Functions app in Postman.

```
"aud": "a5k#####-####-####-####-#########9g3",
"iss": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant id>/v2.0",
"iat": 1629802374,
"nbf": 1629802374,
"exp": 1629806274,
"idp": "live.com",
"name": <my name>,
"oid": <my guid>,
"preferred_username": <my email address>,
"aio": <long string of letters and numbers>,
"azp": "a5k#####-####-####-####-#########9g3",
"azpacr": "1",
"rh": "0.AUMAdyGlEQW7FkCp1RsSSYyl6iM5I8M-MQZNmF3FrOT7pTJDAIg.",
"scp": "user_impersonation",
"sub": "S6HpW4l3X24dlSR9TbiLw8B4WaXuurbELbghhNlo4vY",
"tid": <tenant id>,
"uti": "SeJLTIUGmEu_12E4F4ebAQ",
"ver": "2.0"
```

However, when I run my Blazor Webassembly (standalone) app (created following this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/standalone-with-azure-active-directory-b2c?view=aspnetcore-6.0)) and log in with Azure AD B2C through the app, I get an access token that decodes to something like this. Notice the "ver" is 1.0 and the "azp" does not match the "aud". With this access token, I am unable to call a function from the Azure Functions app. Instead I receive a 401 unauthorized error.

```
"aud": "a5k#####-####-####-####-#########9g3",
"iss": "https://<tenant>.b2clogin.com/<tenant id>/v2.0/",
"iat": 1630011614,
"nbf": 1630011614,
"exp": 1630015214,
"idp": "live.com",
"name": <my name>,
"tfp": "B2C_1_signupsignin",
"azp": "d28#####-####-####-####-#########9g3",
"scp": "user_impersonation",
"sub": "b390b1c6-720a-4d5f-8a9e-5659d38fc484",
"nonce": "0dfb75b1-9fc0-4fca-be52-97706114e3f5",
"ver": "1.0"
```

I found this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-6.0#use-openid-connect-oidc-v20-endpoints) stating that the default Blazor templates use v1.0 authentication, but can be upgraded to v2.0 authentication with the given snippet of code. However the given code requires two nuget packages that complain that there is no runtime library available for the target platform. Does anyone know how to get a v2.0 access token using the Microsoft.Authentication.WebAssembly.Msal library?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this (look at last line):

```
 builder.Services
                .AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
                    options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add(defaultScope);
                    options.UserOptions.RoleClaim = "role";
                    options.ProviderOptions.LoginMode = "Redirect";
                    options.ProviderOptions.Authentication.Authority += "/v2.0";
                })
```

my appsettings.json has:

```json
{
  "AzureAdB2C": {
    "Authority": "https://myproject.b2clogin.com/myproject.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_signupsignin",
    "ClientId": "the-guid",
    "ValidateAuthority": false
  }
}
```

I haven't tested.
Should be required to add also "/oauth2/" before "/v2.0". try it.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help as it just results in the URL having /v2.0 in it twice, which is then an invalid URL.

The URL I'm already seeing in fiddler is https://<tenant>.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_signupsignin/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration

The authorize URL I'm seeing in fiddler is https://<tenant>.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_signupsignin/oauth2/v2.0/authorize